# insert then update generated id back to the table on bulk insert using XML in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]

I have 2 tables **StockDetails,** **StockMail**

First insert Stock name and Expiration Date into **StockDetails** Table(inserting bulk data using XML)

Then Generate Reminder date(7 Days before expiration date) and insert **Stockid**(auto generated id) into **StockMail** Table

Then Update Generated **id**(auto generated id in the StockMail table) into **StockDetails** table.

Please check below working query.

any concurrency issue or any other kind of issue will be come in the future?

I am using **inserted** for get auto generated id of row Is this Right?

or need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @@IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT()

and suggest any query optimization if needed.

Here I am using XML for bulk insert. Which one is better for bulk insert XML or JSON.

```
create procedure USP_Save_Stock      
(      
 @XMLStock nvarchar(max)      
)as      
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;      
BEGIN TRANSACTION       
declare @idocLog int      
declare @stock_info table (id int not null primary key, ExpirationDate datetime not null)      
declare @tbl_mail table (id int, stock_id int)      
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idocLog OUTPUT,@XMLStock       
 
merge StockDetails as tgt      
using (Select StockName,Expiration      
 from OPENXML(@idocLog,'Log/LogChild')      
 WITH(StockName varchar(200),Expiration datetime) ) as src       
on 1 = 0 --never match      
 --when not matched by target     
 when not matched
  then      
        insert (StockName,Expiration)       
        values (StockName,Expiration)   
  output inserted.Stockid,src.Expiration into @stock_info(id, ExpirationDate);      

insert into  StockMail(ReminderDate,StockId) 
output inserted.id, inserted.StockId into @tbl_mail(id, stock_id)
select dateadd(dd, -7, ExpirationDate),id from @stock_info;  

update a set a.MailRefId = b.id
from StockDetails a inner join @tbl_mail b on b.stock_id = a.Stockid
  
exec sp_xml_removedocument @idocLog       
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Use below code to insert data

```
DECLARE @xmldoc NVARCHAR(max)   
SET @xmldoc =  
'<Log>   
<LogChild StockName="AAA" Expiration="2024-01-25"></LogChild>   
<LogChild StockName="BBB" Expiration="2023-05-08"></LogChild> </Log>'  

exec USP_Save_Stock @xmldoc
```